# Rationalizing a numerator

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

My goal was to remove the radical from the numerator of the function:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}-3}{x^2}$$
I first entered my function.

```
f[x_] = (Sqrt[9 + x^2] - 3)/x^2
```

Then I created a list.

```
lst = {Numerator[f[x]], Denominator[f[x]]}
```

Then I multiplied both components of the list by $\sqrt{x^2+9}+3$, simplifying the result.

```
lst = lst*(Sqrt[9 + x^2] + 3) // Simplify
```

Then I changed the list back to a fraction.

```
f[x_] = lst /. {x_, y_} -> x/y
```

Which gave me:
$$\frac{1}{3+\sqrt{9+x^2}}$$

I have a couple of questions.

1. Is there a simpler way to convert my last list back to a fraction?
2. Anyone have a simpler overall process for this particular sequence of algebraic manipulations?
3. I know I've seen a page on Mathematica Stack Exchange where there is a long list of how to simplify and change algebraic expressions, but I've been unable to find it. If someone knows of these links, can they share them?

Thanks.

Comment: `Divide @@ lst` should work for you.

Comment: Simplify[f[x]*(Sqrt[9 + x^2] + 3)]/(Sqrt[9 + x^2] + 3) removes the need for the Divide

Comment: @David, why not just `FullSimplify[f[x]]` for the initial statement?

Comment: @garej Because it is not just the answer that I am interested in helping my students with. Yes, I will show them the Simplify and the FullSimplify command to help them check their answers. But there is a lot of detailed hand work to do in evaluating limits and derivatives and if they don't get the correct answer, I want to be able to show them how they can check some of their step-by-step work in order to discover where they have made their error.

Answer (score 9):

Simplification is in the eye of the beholder.  One approach is

```
f = (Sqrt[9 + x^2] - 3)/x^2;
1/FullSimplify[1/f]
(* 1/(3 + Sqrt[9 + x^2]) *)
FullSimplify[x^2 %]/x^2
(* (-3 + Sqrt[9 + x^2])/x^2 *)
```

You may be thinking of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92686/1063).