# Is there a more efficient way to change the transformations done by Simplify, FullSimplify, etc.?

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, complex

I semi-regularly run into a problem when trying to use `Norm[]` or `Abs[]` to get a symbolic result with `FullSimplify[]`, `Simplify[]`, etc., where MMA and I don't have the same thing in mind for a useful final result.  This basic problem has already been tackled in questions like this: [Advice for Mathematica as Mathematician's Aid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92686/advice-for-mathematica-as-mathematicians-aid).

With the default options to say, `FullSimplify[]`, we have the following:

```
$Assumptions = Element[a | b | c | d, Reals];
FullSimplify[Norm[#]^2 & /@ {a + I b, Sqrt[a + I b], Exp[a + I b]}]

(* {a^2 + b^2, Norm[Sqrt[a + I b]]^2, Norm[E^(a + I b)]^2} *)
```

To get the result I'm looking for, it is pretty straightforward to add a `ComplexityFunction` to penalize results I don't want from `FullSimplify[]`, and then add additional `TransformationFunction`s to get the results I do want, *e.g.*:

```
complexity [e_] := 100 Count[e, _Norm, {0, \[Infinity]}] + LeafCount[e];
transformations = {Automatic, # /. Norm[Sqrt[x_]]^2 :> Sqrt[Re[x]^2 + Im[x]^2] &, # /. Norm[Exp[x_]]^2 :> Exp[2 Re[x]] &};
FullSimplify[{a + I b, Sqrt[a + I b], Exp[a + I b]}, ComplexityFunction -> complexity, TransformationFunctions -> transformations] 

(*{a^2 + b^2, Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], E^(2 a)}*)
```

This works very well for simple cases like this, but it has a few issues.  It doesn't generalize very well to arbitrary expressions, *e.g.* we would need another transformation function to deal with the case of something of the form `Norm[Times[a + I b, c + I d]]^2` if the expression we were simplifying had complex numbers being multiplied.  It also can run prohibitively slow for a sufficiently complicated expression if too many transformation functions are needed.

**Question:** Is there any way in the specific case of `Norm[]` or `Abs[]` when used with one of the simplifying functions (*e.g.* `FullSimplify[]`) to efficiently tell MMA to ignore details about multivalued complex expressions and similar that prevent the simplifications I typically want?  Also, is there a more general way of using transformations other than the defaults in a way that is less computationally expensive than pattern matching as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) before [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)

```
Assuming[{Element[{a, b}, Reals]},
 Norm[#]^2 & /@ {a + I b, Sqrt[a + I b], Exp[a + I b]} // ComplexExpand // 
  FullSimplify]

(*  {a^2 + b^2, Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], E^(2 a)}  *)
```

Comment: Right, I forgot about `ComplexExpand`.  I thought I had tried that in the past with ugly complex expressions and got back long messes full of `Arg` and `Conjugate` and so on, but I just tried it on a long expression and it gave a good result quickly.  Thanks!

Comment: Also I think `ComplexExpand` lets us get rid of `Assuming` since it already assumes everything is real by default.

Comment: @KevinL - If `ComplexExpand` gives a form that you don't like, use [`TargetFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html) option. In general -- and in this case -- you need the `Assuming` for the `FullSimplify`

Comment: I had never noticed `TargetFunctions` before, it looks really useful for this sort of thing.  Thanks again, this is something I will use all the time (and have been doing awkwardly for years now).