# Simplifying an equation into a certain form

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I have the following expression in Mathematica:

$$\beta^{\frac{1}{(1 - \beta)}} - \beta^{\frac{\beta}{(1 - \beta)}}$$

I want to express it as

$$\beta^{\frac{\beta}{(1 - \beta)}}\left (\beta -1 \right)$$

I tried `Factor` and `Simplify` without success.

I would appreciate any advise.

Answer (score 6):

```
expr = b^(1/(1 - b)) - b^(b/(1 - b));
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FullSimplify[expr,ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, Power[_, _?Negative], Infinity] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

reference: [advice-for-mathematica-as-mathematicians-aid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92686/advice-for-mathematica-as-mathematicians-aid)

Comment: How come this only works with `Negative` power, even when `?Negative` isn't used, when an expression with positive power clearly exists.

Comment: Thanks. It works well, but I don't quite understand the logic behind this. I would have to read the reference that you left.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Simplify[Simplify[b^(1/(1-b))-b^(b/(1-b))/.b->(a-1)/a]/.a->1/(1-b)]
(*(b-1)b^(b/(1-b))*)
```

where $b=\beta$.

Comment: More simply `Simplify[expr /. b -> a + 1] /. a -> b - 1`

Comment: @SimonWoods yeah, good catch! I just took `a` to be the exponent of `b`, but your solution does the trick too, and it's much cleaner!