# FullSimplify not simplifying an expression that I think it should

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I wonder why `FullSimplify` cannot simplify this simple expression
$(\frac{(a-1)^3}{b^3})^{1/3}$
where $0<a<1$ and $b<0$. This expression should be equal to $\frac{a-1}{b}$. But when I use this command:

```
FullSimplify[((-1 + a)^3/b^3)^(1/3), 
  a < 1 && a > 0 && b < 0 && Element[b, Reals] && Element[a, Reals]]
```

`Full simplify` just returns the same thing! Any ideas on how can I fixe this?

Comment: Since you are working with real variables, try: `Simplify[((-1 + a)^3/b^3)^(1/3), TransformationFunctions -> PowerExpand]`. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92686/27951 and links therein

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advice for Mathematica as Mathematician's Aid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92686/advice-for-mathematica-as-mathematicians-aid)

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks. I am working with complex expressions. That term is part of the complex expression that I am dealing with.

Comment: Well, that may get dicey then. `PowerExpand` makes implicit assumptions on the variables involved. Perhaps you should amend your example to be more representative of the actual problem you are dealing with.

Comment: Just to add to your frustration :-) `Simplify[((-1 + a)^3/b^3)^(1/3) == (-1 + a)/b, b < 0 && 0 < a < 1]` gives `True`

Comment: Interestingly, `CubeRoot[b^3]` reduces to `b` under `FullSimplify`, but `CubeRoot[(a-1)^3/b^3]` is unchanged.

Comment: @m_goldberg That was a very nice example. It assured me I'm not missing something here (in using FullSimplify).

Comment: @Michael Seifert thanks, this nice trick could solve the problem sometimes. I'm still wondering if there is a more general approach to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As @MarcoB suggests, [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) is a useful tool here, especially when using the [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions) option. When using `Assumptions->Automatic` it is acceptable for [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) to return incorrect results, but for any other boolean setting [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) should always return correct results. So:

```
expr = ((-1 + a)^3 / b^3)^(1/3);
PowerExpand[expr, Assumptions -> 0 < a < 1 && b < 0]
```

> -(1/b) + a/b

and we can be confident that the output of [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) is equivalent to the input under the given assumptions. Now, suppose your expression is more complicated, and using [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) simplifies one part, but complicates a different part. Then, it would be useful to include [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) in the [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions) option of [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify), so that [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) is only applied where it is needed. However, the [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify) assumptions don't automatically get transferred to the transformation functions, so it is a bit complicated. Here is a function that tries to streamline this process:

```
powerSimplify[expr_, assumptions_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{PowerExpand},
    SetOptions[PowerExpand, Assumptions -> assumptions];
    Simplify[expr, assumptions, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, PowerExpand}]
]
```

For your example:

```
powerSimplify[expr, 0 < a < 1 && b < 0]
```

> (-1 + a)/b

as desired. Or, for a different set of assumptions:

```
s = powerSimplify[expr, a > 1 && b < 0]
```

> (-1 + a) (1/b^3)^(1/3)

Let's check:

```
s /. {a -> 2.2, b -> -2.2}
expr /. {a -> 2.2, b -> -2.2}
```

> 0.272727 + 0.472377 I
>
> 0.272727 + 0.472377 I