# Why does Simplify on an equation not remove terms that can't be zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a complicated equation, with a parameter `T` which is positive. The parameter ends up multiplying all terms of my equation, so Mathematica factors it out the front. But for some reason `Simplify` (or `FullSimplify`) refuses to factor it out, unless the rest of the equation is simple.

```
Simplify[T (b +  e (-1 + c) (1 + Tanh[a])) == 0, T > 0]

(* T (b + (-1 + c) e (1 + Tanh[a])) == 0 *)
```

If I make the equation slightly simpler, Mathematica has no problem with removing the `T`:

```
Simplify[T (b +  e (c) (1 + Tanh[a])) == 0, T > 0]

(* b + c e + c e Tanh[a] == 0 *)
```

My actual equation is much longer, but I want to be able to check that `T` does not exist in it.

Comment: How simple an expression is depends on how you quantify simplicity. If you provide `Simplify` with a different complexity function (e.g. `ComplexityFunction -> (StringLength[ToString[#1]] &)`, you can get the T factored out, at the expense of some other reorganization of your equation. See also [(92686)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92686/27951).

Comment: It is not clear, what do you want. Mathematica does factor it out in your first expression. You seem to mean that Mma does not automatically divide by the both equation parts by it, do you? You have written that your equation always has T as a factor. If I understood this right, there is a simple way to get rid of it: `equation/.T->1`. Have fun!

Comment: It might be helpful to try `Reduce` to see possible solutions. If `T==0` is one of them, it suggests (but does not guarantee) that you can factor it out. `Reduce[tt (b + e (c - 1) (1 + Tanh[a])) == 0, tt]` = ` (*   b == -(-1 + c) e (1 + Tanh[a]) || tt == 0    *)`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Mathematica factors $T$ out yes, but I'm telling it that $T>0$ in the assumptions, so it should be able to remove it entirely.

Comment: @MarcoB, for any complexity function, removing the T entirely would make it simpler.

Comment: Maybe you can do something with `PolynomialGCD`? Evaluating `Trace[Simplify[(1 + 2 a^2 (a + b)) T == 0, T != 0], _[___, T, ___]|T, TraceInternal -> True]` reveals that `Simplify` actually uses `PolynomialGCD` to figure out that the l.h.s. is divisible by `T`, but it doesn't use that fact properly. Not sure why...

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting case. First, here is a more minimal example. While `Simplify` does not eliminate T:

```
Simplify[(1 + 2 a^2 (a + b)) T == 0, T != 0]
(* (1 + 2 a^2 (a + b)) T == 0 *)
```

`FullSimplify` does the job in this case:

```
FullSimplify[(1 + 2 a^2 (a + b)) T == 0, T != 0]
(* 1 + 2 a^2 (a + b) == 0 *)
```

`Simplify` does work for much more complicated cases such as

```
Simplify[(1 + 2 a^2 (a + b) + x^1/3 - Coth[Gamma[42^z] I]) T == 0, T != 0]
(* 3 + 6 a^3 + 6 a^2 b + x + 3 I Cot[Gamma[42^z]] == 0 *)
```

So the complexity by itself is not the issue.

Now, to a possible solution to your problem. In the MMA documentation for `ComplexityFunction` the "Properties & Relations" section contains the complexity function `Simplify` uses by default to assess the complexity of a term. You may modify this function such that any appearance of T is extremely expensive:

```
SimplifyCountX[p_] := Which[
    p===T, 10^6,
    Head[p]===Symbol, 1,
    IntegerQ[p], If[p==0,1,Floor[N[Log[2,Abs[p]]/Log[2,10]]]+If[p>0,1,2]],
    Head[p]===Rational, SimplifyCountX[Numerator[p]]+SimplifyCountX[Denominator[p]]+1,
    Head[p]===Complex, SimplifyCountX[Re[p]]+SimplifyCountX[Im[p]]+1,
    NumberQ[p], 2,
    True, SimplifyCountX[Head[p]]+If[Length[p]==0,0,Plus@@(SimplifyCountX/@(List@@p))]
]
```

The first case within `Which[...]` is the modification. Everything else is like in the documentation.

Using this complexity function things should at least improve for you:

```
Simplify[(1 + 2 a^2 (a + b)) T == 0, T != 0, ComplexityFunction -> SimplifyCountX]
(* 1 + 2 a^3 + 2 a^2 b == 0 *)
```

I also tested this with more complicated functions, and it seems to work.

To make sure if it worked, use

```
FreeQ[..., T]
```

on the simplified expression.

Answer (score 1):

"I want to be able to check that `T` does not exist in it."

I assume you mean you want to check that you *can* factor `T` out. So, expanding on @AlexeiBoulbitch's suggestion, remove it, multiply by it, and check for equality.

```
expression = T (b + e (-1 + c) (1 + Tanh[a]))
Simplify[T (expression /. T -> 1) == expression]
(* True *)
```

Comment: But this doesn't work if the factor is $T^2$ for example.

Comment: It'm still not entirely clear on what you want, but `MatchQ[Cancel[expression/(expression /. T -> 1)], Power[T, _]]` will check to see if you can factor any power of T out.

Comment: To be honest, I mostly just want to understand why Mathematica doesn't remove it in this case, when it can.

Comment: `Simplify` doesn't exhaustively try every available transformation. It has no reliable way to to tell it's "done". It makes decisions based on the informed guesses its developers built into it. There's no way for the user to understand why it didn't choose a particular transformation trajectory, and it would probably not be illuminating if you could.

Answer (score 1):

```
Simplify[Expand[T (b + e (-1 + c) (1 + Tanh[a]))] == 0, T > 0]
(* b + c e + c e Tanh[a] == e (1 + Tanh[a]) *)
```

eliminates `T`.  Perhaps, this works because `Expand` makes the `LeafCount` of the equation larger, giving `Simplify` more options to try things.  (Not a very satisfying explanation, I admit.  Nonetheless, I have seen `Expand` before `Simplify` help in the other situations.)  To gather all terms to the left side of the equation again, use

```
Simplify[# - Last[%]] & /@ %
(* b + (-1 + c) e + (-1 + c) e Tanh[a] == 0 *)
```

**Addendum**

Motivated by the resourceful (+1) answer of [JEM_Mosig](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/35390/jem-mosig), I offer the simpler alternative

```
cf[e_] := LeafCount[e] + 100 Count[e, T, Infinity]
Simplify[T (b + e (-1 + c) (1 + Tanh[a])) == 0, T > 0, ComplexityFunction -> cf]
(* b + (-1 + c) e + (-1 + c) e Tanh[a] == 0 *)
```

Note that this answer is taken almost directly from [Mathematica documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html).  Once again, it appears that `Simplify` works better when the achievable savings in `ComplexityFunction` is large.