# Simplify, ComplexityFunction, and expression rearrangement

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Context: Mathematica is being used to simplify expressions. These expressions are then exported to be used in a C-family language. Naturally enough, desiderata include execution speed, and avoidance of overflow.

As a simple example, consider `z = ((a b)/c)^2`. As entered, this is one multiply, one division, and one square.

Mathematica rearranges this to three squarings, one division into 1, and then two multiplies: `Times[Power[a,2],Power[b,2],Power[c,-2]]`. If output in `CForm` this is three squarings, a multiply and a division. So Mathematica’s form would be more CPU work. Mathematica’s form also has more risk of an overflow, such as when a = c = 10^200 and b ≈ 1.

The following doesn’t help.

```
FullSimplify[
    z 
    , ComplexityFunction -> (1000 Count[#, Power, Infinity] 
                          + LeafCount[#] &)
    , Assumptions -> c != 0
]
```

Please, what’s the best way to instruct ‘simplify for something like CPU efficiency in a compiled language’?

Relevant link (even though I was unable to apply its lessons): [Advice for Mathematica as Mathematician's Aid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92686/advice-for-mathematica-as-mathematicians-aid/92689)

Thank you.

Comment: maybe this isn't what you want,but how about this ? https://github.com/njpipeorgan/MathCompile

Comment: Useful to some, so worth the link — thank you — but not for this question. The question isn’t how to take a mass of Mathematica and convert or compile it. Instead it asks how to get Mathematica to `Simplify` things into a form that is sensible in an imperative language.

Comment: *Mathematica* generally reduces expressions to a standard form intended for computer algebra. If you're exporting to a compiled language, optimizing procedural code is your compiler's responsibility.

Comment: But is it easy to have Mathematica simplify expressions for a different purpose? I’ve failed to do so, and was hoping that a generous respondent might see a clean way through the problem. Even if, or because, it isn’t Mathematica’s default behaviour.

Comment: The reason Mathematica behaves the way it does is because `Power`  automatically expands over `Times`.  It has nothing to do with `Simplify`.  Therefore, your best bet is, in your code, avoid using `Power`, and opt for your own power function–call it `pow`–which does not automatically expand.  Then, add a `CForm` definition to `pow` that makes the appropriate transcription to C code.

Comment: The target here is not that any function does or doesn’t expand over another. Please allow the target to be more general, and therefore of broader use. Can Mathematica (which might mean `Simplify`, but I’ll happily step back from that) arrange an expression for something like CPU efficiency?

Comment: Can you provide any larger examples?  It would be easier to test approaches if we didn't have to craft cases ourselves.

Comment: Not readily. I’d need to carefully count computations and minimise them. This example, as-is except for a change of parameter names, was enough for me to know that Mathematica’s `Simplify` wasn’t doing anything like what `CpuEfficiencify` should. (I’m trying to avoid doing the hard work by hand.)