# How to Force the PolyGamma[0, x] function or the HarmonicNumber[ x ] function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, summation

I'm crunching some infinite summations, and sometimes Mathematica generates results that have the `PolyGamma[0, x]` function (which is the Digamma) and sometimes the `HarmonicNumber[ ]`. I'd like to choose one or the other as to what's generated. My fallback is to use a rule for replacement, but curious as to how Mathematica chooses what to generate.

Here's an interesting example:

The first one has `PolyGamma` in it, both before and after `FullSimplify`

```
res = m + Sum[2 (m - k + 1) 1/(1 - 4 (1 - k)^2), {k, 2, m}] // FullSimplify
(* 1/2 (EulerGamma + 2/(-1 + 2 m) + Log[4] + PolyGamma[0, -(1/2) + m]) *)
```

This one, same as the one above but without the presum of `m`, resolves with `PolyGamma`

```
res = Sum[2 (m - k + 1) 1/(1 - 4 (1 - k)^2), {k, 2, m}] 
(* (2 + 2 m - 4 m^2 + PolyGamma[0, 1/2] - 2 m PolyGamma[0, 1/2] - PolyGamma[0, -(1/2) + m] + 2 m PolyGamma[0, -(1/2) + m])/(2 (-1 + 2 m))
```

But if simplified, goes to the Harmonic Number

```
res // FullSimplify
(* (2 + (-1 + 2 m) HarmonicNumber[-(3/2) + m] - Log[4] + 2 m (1 - 2 m + Log[4]))/(-2 + 4 m) *)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is "simpler" or more complex is a very subjective question. The topic has come up a few times before (see e.g. my previous answer to [Advice for Mathematica as Mathematician's Aid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92689/27951) and links therein).

The `Simplify` functions fiddle with an expression systematically in an attempt to minimize a pre-defined "complexity function", which is loosely based on the [`LeafCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html) of the expression (the exact function is somewhere in the documentation of `Simplify`, if I recall correctly). Even small changes (e.g. `PolyGamma` vs. `HarmonicNumber`) can *significantly* affect this complexity measure.

Fortunately, however, you can supply your own complexity function using the [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)option, and bias it in the direction  you prefer. For instance:

```
res1 = m + Sum[2 (m - k + 1) 1/(1 - 4 (1 - k)^2), {k, 2, m}]
res2 = Sum[2 (m - k + 1) 1/(1 - 4 (1 - k)^2), {k, 2, m}]

simpPoly = FullSimplify[#, ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 10 Count[#, _HarmonicNumber, All] &)] &
simpHarmonic = FullSimplify[#, ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 10 Count[#, _PolyGamma, All] &)] &
```

The first one severely penalizes expressions that contain `HarmonicNumber`, thus preferring those that contain `PolyGamma`; the second does the opposite. Here are the results:

```
simpHarmonic /@ {res1, res2}
```

[image: expression with only HarmonicNumber]

```
simpPoly /@ {res1, res2}
```

[image: expression with only PolyGamma]

Comment: Ah, I don't have to write an answer anymore... :)

Comment: @J.M Thank you! :-)

Comment: Very cool, muchos gracias.

Comment: @MikeY You are very welcome!